# Thread memory management of ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading

My doubt is that HashTable get() method is synchronized for read. But this limitation has been removed for ConcurrentHashMap. However only synchronized blocks access the latest values from memory. If thats the case will it access the latest value if some other Thread has updated it and then cached the value locally. Hows does it do this.
Further do Reentrant locks also fetch and update the latest values from memory like synchronized blocks.
Thanks

Comment: Is your question basically whether the java.util.concurrent libraries provide memory consistency guarantees?

Comment: Yeah. It might sound silly. But i didn't read anywhere that it does. So just confirming.

Comment: check out the javadoc for the interface ConcurrentMap

Comment: Yes it does. Whether you use lock or synchronized block, that will guarantee you see latest updated value.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Comment: ReentrantLocks are also thread safe, they would be pointless if they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is pretty clear on this:

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update
>   operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update
>   operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any
>   (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

The "happens-before" text specifically refers the behavior of java [memory consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

Comment: Thanks. Also my point is how does it manage to get that latest values without synchronizing or locking the read operation. I mean whats the mechanism internally used.

Comment: @HariJustForFun The source is included in the JDK, you can study that.

Answer (score 1):

> However only synchronized blocks access the latest values from memory

There you are wrong: `volatile` reads access the latest value with no locking. In more general terms, the essential concern is whether the *happens before* relationship defined by the Java Memory Model has been established between writes and reads. `ConcurrentHashMap` makes use of `volatile` variables to guarantee *happens before*.

Comment: That was a typo. What i meant was out of the two i.e synchronization and no synchronization. But thanks a lot for the answer. Makes sense.